# Why can't I stop myself from shooting the President?

Tags: ace-combat-7-skies-unknown

I've started playing Ace Combat 7: Skies Unknown and I'm still pretty early in the game. I'm stuck on Mission 04: Rescue, where you need to discretely fly to a space elevator to assist with the breakout of President Harland.

I've gotten pretty capable at evading the radar signals surrounding the structure, and I seem to be able to protect the president's escape vehicle for most of the mission, but once the escape pilot is killed and President Harland takes over flying the Osprey VTOL I can't seem to avoid shooting him.

Once he's in control of the vehicle, is he accidentally turning off it's identifier and accidentally marking it as a target? It's really hectic when defending and as a new pilot I usually lock on targets and fire without checking too thoroughly. Despite this, I've tried retrying the (thankfully short) mission three times, yet I keep accidentally launching missile at him.

I don't have this friendly fire issue with other allied planes. What's making it so easy to shoot at the President?

Comment: ...Annnnnd Arqade is now on an FBI watchlist. Say hi to whoever at the FBI gets stuck watching this site!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's intentional, and how the game's story goes.

Comment: It’s certainly unclear because it says “mission failed” in the ending debrief, but you’re correct- I was able to go to the next mission

Comment: The friendly fire is caused by some missiles that came out of nowhere. You can complete this entire mission just with your machine guns, bomb for ground target etc, in other words without using any missiles... still the mission fails because of friendly-fire missile.

Answer (score 3):

It's overall impossible to make any form of decisions for how the game progresses - it's extremely linear. If you actually fail a mission you have to replay it and you won't get to the debriefing/summary. The debriefing afterwards telling you that you fail etc is just part of the story. "In character" some missions are a success, some are failures, all part of the story.

A lot of dogfights are heavily scripted so that the outcome can only be one. In this one an enemy plane will keep tailing the president's plane and as you aim for that one you'll shoot the wrong one through scripts. In other fights you can shoot some 20+ missiles at a NPC plane but the game won't let you blow it up until some dialogue is done.